# Ignite TimeServer sync behind NAT

Tags: ignite

We're currently running Apache Ignite in a docker container but are having problems with the time server sync. Each node is reporting all the known ip addresses which later is used by a remote peer to send a time sync message over UDP.
Is there a way to specify the externally reachable ip address that the peers will use for time sync?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to set to every node a network interface it should use for all network related communications using `IgniteConfiguration.setLocalHost(...)` method. The time server will use the addresses specified this way for its needs as well.

However it's not critical that the time server is non workable on your side because it's used for cache `CLOCK` mode which is discouraged for usage.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the use for the time server. After reading a bit about the CLOCK mode I realize that I don't need it. However the IgniteConfiguration.setLocalHost(..) needs an IP that exists on the local machine which is not the case for us since the docker layer works like a firewall where the externally accessible IP is not the IP inside the docker container.